# Is it possible for an animal to use nerve gas as a defense mechanism?

Tags: biology, creature-design, xenobiology

Is it possible for an animal to use nerve gas as a defense mechanism?

I'm making a book, journal thingy and I may decide to make an animal that uses nerve gas as a "defense mechanism" and by nerve gas I mean like Tabun, Sarin, Soman, or Cyclosarin.

You could possibly use the bombardier beetle as a reference.

Please make it seem atleast a-bit realistic.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding Jelli (may I call you Jelli?). Nice first question, enjoy the site. Just a thought, but would an aerosolized nerve agent work for you (fine droplets in the air) or must it be gas?

Comment: Why do you want/require the gas to affect the nerves specifically rather than some other body-system?

Comment: @ARogueAnt. You can call me Jello or Jelli or whatever you like, but I would be fine with an aerosolized nerve agent.

Comment: @I-Stand-With-Palestine im not sure, i just thought it would be a cool idea to add into an organsim. And nerve gas seems quite dangerous considering world powers such as the U.S. and Russia signed a thingy to ban it in war.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Spitting cobras can shoot liquid neurotoxins.**

[image: spitting cobra]
https://theconversation.com/spitting-cobras-may-have-evolved-unique-venom-to-defend-from-ancient-humans-153570

Cobra venom contains neurotoxins as well as other toxins.  It is a defensive mechanism, evolved to hurt the things it hits.

Neurotoxic snake venoms hit many of the same targets as nerve gases.  Sarin for example hits acetylcholinesterases.

[Multifunctional Toxins in Snake Venoms and Therapeutic Implications: From Pain to Hemorrhage and Necrosis](https://www.frontiersin.org/articles/10.3389/fevo.2019.00218/full)

> Three-Finger Toxins (3FTXs) Three-fingers toxins (3FTXs) are
> non-enzymatic neurotoxins ranging from 58 to 81 residues that contain
> a three-finger fold structure stabilized by disulfide bridges...  For
> example, α-neurotoxins inhibit muscle acetylcholine receptors (nAChR)
> (Changeux, 1990), κ-neurotoxins inhibits neuronal AChR (Grant and
> Chiappinelli, 1985), muscarinic toxins inhibit muscarinic receptors
> (Marquer et al., 2011), fasciculins inhibit acetylcholinesterase
> (AChE) (Marchot et al., 1998),...

Snake venom is of course a liquid though it can be sprayed.  Usually nerve gases also start as a sprayed liquid that either continues as tiny droplets or volatilizes.

Snake venoms will probably all be proteins and none of the nerve gases listed are.  But snake venoms can do a lot of what nerve gases do and additional things besides (check out [fasciculins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fasciculin)!).  So the answer is yes.